# Efecto Blur al fondo en html

Tags: blur

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, me pueden colaborar estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programacion pero no se como agregar otro estilo css dentro del html, siendo mas especificos necesito poner un Efecto Blur al fondo en html

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Español, por favor edita tu pregunta, quita la imagen y añade el código en modo texto, porque no todo el mundo puede verla saludos :-)

Answer (score 0):

Investiga sobre la propiedad backdrop-filter. Podrías usar backdrop-filter: blur(5px).
Tendrías que añadirselo al body igual que la propiedad background que ya tienes con una imagen. Aunque se recomienda usar una hoja de estilos aparte y linkearla al html mediante `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">`

Comment: Gracias, Que pena molestarte nuevamente no me coje los estilos en el localhost:

Comment: Debe ser por el href. En vez de jvh-crud/styles.css,  pon solo styles.css, ya que están en el mismo nivel de la estructura de directorios.